# Get the average from multiple items

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose I have a list like this

```
[name1, number1], [name2, number2], [name3, number 3]
```

For example

```
[John, 86], [Joe, 94], [bob, 45], [andy, 34]
```

I'm trying to print out everyone above number 80 and get the average. So in this case I want to output

```
John Joe 90
```

What is the most simple structure I can use to do this?

Comment: im not sure what you are asking.

Comment: try to put yourself in our shoe and read your question, and see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of arrays, each with two elements, the first being the name and the second being the age, you can represent it like this:

```
var people = [["John", 86], ["Joe", 90], ["Bob", 45], ["Andy", 34]];
```

and you can take the people over 80, get a list of their names, and average their ages like this:

```
var sum = 0;
var length = 0;
var names = [];
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  var person = people[i];
  if(person[1] >= 80) {
    sum += person[1];
    length++;
    names.push(person[0]);
  }
}
alert(names.join(" "));  //alerts "John Joe"
alert(sum / length);     //alerts 88
```

You can see it on action [on this jsFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/LVcLy/).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an array of arrays. What you can do is iterate through the parent arrays, and then check each nested array. If the nested array contains a score greater than 80 in the second spot (`[1]`) then you can add that score to a total and that name in the first spot (`[0]`) to a string. Once everything has been added, divide the total by the additions and place it at the end of the string with the names in it.

```
function GetNameAverageString(numberOfUsers,arrayOfData){
 var runningCount = 0;//number of users added to return string
 var total = 0;//total of scores from added users
 var names = "";//return string which will contain names and average
 for( var nestedArray in arrayOfData ){
  if( parseInt(arrayOfData[nestedArray][1]) < 81 ) continue;//only scores over 80
  names += arrayOfData[nestedArray][0] + " ";//append the name to the return string
  runningCount++;//add to the count of users recorded
  total += parseInt(arrayOfData[nestedArray][1]);//add to the score total
 }
 var average = total / runningCount;//calculate average score based on users added
 names += average.toString();//append the score to the end of the names
 return names;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataArray = [["John", 86], ["Joe", 94], ["Bob", 45], ["Andy", 34]];
var count = 0;
var total = 0;
var peopleOverEighty = "";
for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
  if(dataArray[i][1] > 80) {
    count++;
    total += dataArray[i][1];
    peopleOverEighty += dataArray[i][0] + " ";
  }
}
alert(peopleOverEighty + " " + (total/count));
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a datastructure like this:

```
var data = [[john, 86], [joe, 94], [bob, 45], [andy, 34]];
```

And you want to filter out everyone below 80:

```
data = data.filter(function(value,index,array){return (value[1]<80);});
```

And get the average:

```
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
    total += data[i];
}
avg = total/data.length;
```

Is this what you required?

Comment: Note that this only works natively on ECMAScript-5 compliant browsers. For IE<=8 you will need a shim.

Comment: Right. A shim is provided [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

> *"What is the most simple structure I can use to do this?"*

`Array.prototype.reduce` is meant for this:

```
var arr = [["John", 86], ["Joe", 94], ["bob", 45], ["andy", 34]],
    result;
(result = arr.reduce(function(ret, arr) {
    if (arr[1] >= 80) {
        ret[0].push(arr[0]);
        ret[1] += arr[1];
    }
    return ret;
}, [[], 0]))[1] /= result[0].length;
```

You can get a `.reduce()` shim from MDN.